# Shiny validate + eventReactive - does not work?

Tags: r, shiny

Shiny [validate](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html) does not seem to work on eventReactive:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
      switch <- input$switch

      if (switch == "hide") {
        # https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/update-input-demo.html
        updateNumericInput(session, "n", "X", min = 0, max = 100, value = 0)
      }

  })

  ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    validate(
      need(input$switch != "hide", "Please select a data set")
    )

    input$n
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    ntext()
  })
})


shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Click the button"),
  sidebarPanel(

    radioButtons(
        inputId = "switch",
        label = "Select hide or show:",
        choices = c(
            "Show" = "show",
            "Hide" = "hide"
        ),
        selected = NULL,
        inline = FALSE
    ),

    conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.switch == 'show'",
        numericInput("n", "N:", min = 0, max = 100, value = 0)
    ),

    actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("text")
  )
))
```

Any ideas how can I use it with eventReactive?

Comment: try moving your validate clause into your render text statement rather than as an eventReactive

Comment: @Phi did that already but still the same...

Comment: ok lets back up for a second. why are you making `ntext()` at all? I think youre trying to make make a conditional panel appear if show is selected and then output the results of that panel to screen after the button is pressed, is that correct?

Comment: @Phi it is for the reason of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44311869/r-shiny-prevent-the-app-from-plotting-on-start

Comment: i don't want to fire any code until the button is clicked.

Comment: im very confused on what isnt working. Which code do you not want to 'fire'? I've tried the above and unless I misunderstand what youre trying to accomplish it seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Phi I want to click the `go` button first before firing `ntext()`.

Comment: As far as I can tell it is working fine. Could it be you have mixed up the way the command is supposed to work? `validate` displays an error message when the watched condition is `FALSE` (i.e. the radio button is set to `Show`), and does nothing when it is TRUE (i.e. the radio button is set to `Hide`). And that is what it is doing.